# Can the struct sockaddr passed to bind be a local variable?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I would like to have a simple function to setup the server side of a UDP connection that just takes the port to use and returns the socket descriptor.  Is this possible?  Or does the `struct sockaddr` variable passed into `bind` need to stick around?  This is the function I want:

```
int UDP_Init( int port )
{
    int sockfd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP );
    if ( sockfd < 0 )
    {
        perror( "ERROR opening UDP socket" );
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    bzero( (char*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr) );
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons( port );
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( INADDR_ANY );

    if ( bind( sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr) ) < 0 )
    {
        perror( "ERROR binding UDP socket" );
        return -1;
    }

    return sockfd;
}
```

Will this work?  Or do I have to keep the `sockaddr_in` structure linked to the socket descriptor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is fine.

Once you `bind` a socket, the `sockaddr` struct you pass in doesn't need to be retained in any way.

The reason `bind()` takes a `struct sockaddr *` is because there are several structs it can accept (`struct sockaddr_in` for IPv4, `struct sockaddr_in6` for IPv6, `struct sockaddr_un` for UNIX domain sockets, etc).  Each of these structs is a different size, so the function takes a pointer (the use of `sockaddr*` is for historic reasons) and the size of the struct being pointed at.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work fine, when you call the bind   the underlying Network stack needs the struct sockaddr information to bind the passed socket descriptor to port and address you passed via struct sockaddr. After that you can use the socket descriptor for the further communication.